# ruby on rails syntax highlighting for sublime like cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, sublimetext3

Right now I am using RailsCasts Color Scheme on Sublime Text 3(Linux). Its hard to recognize embedded Ruby from normal text because all of that is white.

Also at the bottom right of sublime text it says file type as `ERB` because I have installed ERB Syntax highlighting from package manager. But, I don't find any syntax highlighting for Ruby On Rails in package manager.

I wish to make the erb stand out from normal text. How would I do that?

[image]

Also my Guardfile looks pretty messed up. Cloud9 has better highlighting for GuardFile. Its nearly impossible to read this file. How do I use better color scheme for all Ruby on Rails projects

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the view tab, there should be a path like this

View > Syntax > Rails > HTML (rails)

Comment: The color of embedded Ruby and Guardfile is still same.

Comment: hmm that's weird, it could be just your color scheme that you're using.

Comment: what color scheme would you suggest for ROR?